# Authors details

Tags: author

Following the execution of the LaTeX file, my desire is to obtain "*Corresponding Author. Email" in place of "*Corresponding Author(s). Email(s)", i.e., I want to remove (s). Given below are the commands used in my file. Suggestions are welcome.

```
\author*[1,2]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\author[2,3]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\author[1,2]{\fnm{Third} \sur{Author}}\email{iiiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[3]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{610101}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Is "*Corresponding Author(s). Email(s)" coming from a style file? If you have a .sty file, that would be the first place to look.

If that doesn't work, can you also share a minimum working example for someone else to replicate your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately your code doesn't compile. Please add the missing lines. Thank you